# requested product doesn't exist in backend model

Tags: magento2

I need to change product attribute value after saving it, but it gives me `requested product doesn't exist` when I save the product

```
 class myClass extends Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend
 { 
public function afterSave($object){
    // your after save logic


    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productRepository = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
    $product = $productRepository->getById($productId);
    $product->setName($productName);
    $productRepository->save($product);

    return parent::afterSave($object);
}
```

Comment: $productId is undefined

Comment: No, it's defined, I've defined it

Answer (score 0):

You should use "beforeSave" when saving data.

In your case it maybe loop forever

Comment: why loop forever?